# Lua DSL or clever closures?

Tags: list, lua

I'm cutting my teeth with Lua and trying to implement some list processing logic. I'm not sure if I truly grasp the power of coroutines and anonymous functions but I'm trying. I know how these things work in other scripting languages like Ruby/Groovy/Javascript and I'm wanting to do something equally as clever in Lua. Here's what I've come up with as an example:

```
model = { { player = "Cliff", age = 35, gender = "male" }, { player = "Ally", age = 36, gender = "female" }, { player = "Jasmine", age = 13, gender = "female" }, { player = "Lauren", age = 6.5, gender = "female" } }

function allplayers()
    return coroutine.create(function()
        for idx, each in ipairs(model) do
            coroutine.yield(idx, each)
        end
    end)
end

function handlePlayers(source)
    local status, idx, each = coroutine.resume(source)
    while each do
        print(idx, each.player)
        status, idx, each = coroutine.resume(source)
    end
end

function having(source, predicate)
    return coroutine.create(function()
        local status, idx, each = coroutine.resume(source)
        while each do
            if predicate(each)  then
                coroutine.yield(idx, each)
            end
            status, idx, each = coroutine.resume(source)
        end
    end)
end

handlePlayers(having(allplayers(), function(each) return each.age < 30 end))
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to write code like:

```
allplayers(having(function(each) return each.age < 30 end))
```

or even better:

```
allplayers(having({each.age < 30 }))
```

to produce the same output but I can't quite get my head around how or even if this can be done. What I have above seems way too redundant with all the iteration and loops and all. Is there a groovier way to do this? (Boy I miss coding in Groovy, because there was always a groovier way to do something...)

Comment: "Boy I miss coding in Groovy, because there was always a groovier way to do something..." If you're going to program in Lua, then program in *Lua*. Stop wishing the language were something else and learn to do things the Lua way.

Comment: Relax! I like Lua and that's why I'm taking my time learning it. :) I only made the groovy reference because that was the 1st thing that came to mind when I posted, "there's gotta be a Groovier way to do this..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to reuse the filtered result, consider an iterator:

```
model = {
  { player = "Cliff", age = 35, gender = "male" },
  { player = "Ally", age = 36, gender = "female" },
  { player = "Jasmine", age = 13, gender = "female" },
  { player = "Lauren", age = 6.5, gender = "female" }
}

function model:having(predicate)
    local index = 0 
    return function()
        while true do
            index = index + 1
            if index > #self then break end
            if predicate(self[index]) then return self[index] end
        end
    end
end

for item in model:having(function(m) return m.age < 30 end) do
    print(item.player)
end
```

Comment: Ooh I like this approach! Much cleaner than what I was doing and very close to my desired syntax! :) Let me look over the other answers before I select the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly overcomplicated and overdesigned. You want to filter one list via a predicate. So do that; it's a simple loop. Just write it.

Even if you absolutely must do this in a functional style (Lua is not a functional language. It can work that way, but it's not functional), coroutines aren't appropriate.

Observe:

```
model = {
  { player = "Cliff", age = 35, gender = "male" },
  { player = "Ally", age = 36, gender = "female" },
  { player = "Jasmine", age = 13, gender = "female" },
  { player = "Lauren", age = 6.5, gender = "female" }
}

function for_each_array(list, operation)
  for key, value in ipairs(list) do
    operation(value)
  end
end

function filter_if(list, predicate)
  return function(value)
    if(predicate(value)) then
      list[#list + 1] = value
    end
  end
end

local list = {}
for_each_array(model, filter_if(list, function(each) return each.age < 30 end))

for_each_array(list, function(each) print(each.player) end)
```

See? No need for coroutines at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how Lua is not a functional language? Besides first-class functions, which usually is enough to be allowed in the club, it also has proper tail calls (which JavaScript, Python and even some Lisps lack).

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I'm trying to achieve. My above example is intentionally trivial and intended as a learning exercise as well as a way of pushing/discovering the language's limits. I'm looking for a syntax-bending approach that I could use on more involved code. Such an approach would read elegantly and not be overly verbose. I'll avoid a debate over functional vs. non-functional.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Underscore.lua](http://mirven.github.com/underscore.lua/) modeled after the [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) JavaScript library.

Your example would look like this:

```
_ = require 'underscore'
model = {
  { player = "Cliff", age = 35, gender = "male" },
  { player = "Ally", age = 36, gender = "female" },
  { player = "Jasmine", age = 13, gender = "female" },
  { player = "Lauren", age = 6.5, gender = "female" }
}
result1 = _.select(model, function(p) return p.age < 30 end) -- traditional way
result2 = _(model):select(function(p) return p.age < 30 end) -- object-oriented style, calls can be chained
assert(_.is_equal(result1, result2))
```

Note that Lua won't give you any other syntax sugar (apart from the `:` operator). If you really want shorter syntax, you should look at [Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/), which allows you to change the language, and provides the following short function syntax out-of-the-box:

```
result = _.select(model, |p| p.age < 30)
```

Comment: Very interesting approach but I'm trying to keep my dependencies minimal. I'll definitely look deeper into underscore and metaLua for future needs.

Comment: Optional parenthesis on one-parameter calls (like in the `require` call on this answer) is also an ofter-forgotten syntax sugar provided by Lua. Easily abused, but useful for DSLs.